# winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 7.0.0.0~focal-1)

Tags: github-actions, wine, ubuntu-22.04

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 7.0.0.0~focal-1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I am using ubuntu-20.04

```
  sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
  sudo wget -qO- https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key | sudo apt-key add -
  sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main'
  sudo apt update
  sudo apt -y install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem on debian 11. Tried the solution proposed here(https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=35417) and it worked for me:
First install wine-stable-amd64 or wine-stable-i386.
Then *sudo apt -y install --install-recommends winehq-stable* again

Comment: didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get install wine-stable-amd64

or

sudo apt-get install wine-stable-i386

sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable